# SD Card Write Problem

Tags: arduino, sd, gsm

In my project I download a ".hex" file from FTP via GSM connection and write it to a SD card. But I have a problem: I download file and all loops work well but when I access the file on computer I always see 24600 bytes file size :(

Can anyone help me solve the problem why this happens?
Thanks.

```cpp
// FTPRECV Command
#ifdef _AT_FTPRECV_

    #ifdef GSM_Debug
        Terminal_GSM.Text(GSM_Console_Boot_X, 9, WHITE, F("%       "));
    #endif

    // Chain Control
    if (this->Config.Control.Function) {

        // Reset Control Variables
        this->Config.Control.Error_WD = 0;
        this->Config.Control.Response = false;

        // Declare SD File Object
        File SD_File;

        // Activate Mux
        DDRC |= 0b00000001;
        PORTC |= 0b00000001;
        delay(10);

        // Start SD Card
        if (SD.begin(53)) {

            // Control for Existing File
            if (SD.exists(this->Config.SD_File_Name)) {

                // Remove Existing File
                SD.remove(this->Config.SD_File_Name);

                // SD Message
                #ifdef GSM_Debug
                    Terminal_GSM.Text(GSM_Console_Boot_X, 50, GREEN, F("File Exist and Deleted."));
                #endif

            }

            // Open File for Write
            SD_File = SD.open(this->Config.SD_File_Name, FILE_WRITE);

            // SD Message
            #ifdef GSM_Debug
                Terminal_GSM.Text(GSM_Console_Boot_X, 50, GREEN, F("SD Opened  "));
            #endif

            // Get Time
            uint32_t _Download_Start_Time = millis();

            // Set Data Variable
            char _Data[this->Config.Buffer_Size + 10];

            // Loop for File Size
            for (uint32_t i = 0; i < this->LoopSize(); i++) {

                // Set Data Variable
                memset(_Data, '\0', this->Config.Buffer_Size + 10);

                // Reset Control Variables
                this->Config.Control.Error_WD = 0;
                this->Config.Control.Response = false;

                // Process Command
                while (!this->Config.Control.Response) {

                    // Send Command
                    this->Config.Control.Response = AT_Command_Set::FTPRECV(this->Config.Buffer_Size, _Data);

                    // Set WD Variable
                    this->Config.Control.Error_WD++;

                    // Control for WD
                    if (this->Config.Control.Error_WD > 4) break;;

                }

                // Print File
                SD_File.flush();
                delay(1);

                // Calculate Download Time
                this->Variables.Download_Time = (millis() - _Download_Start_Time) / 1000;

                // SD Message
                #ifdef GSM_Debug
                    Terminal_GSM.Text(GSM_Console_Boot_X, 10, WHITE, String(this->Percent(i)));
                    Terminal_GSM.Text(GSM_Console_Boot_X, 30, WHITE, String(this->Variables.Download_Time));
                #endif

            }

            delay(1);
            SD_File.close();

        } else {

            // SD Message
            #ifdef GSM_Debug
                Terminal_GSM.Text(GSM_Console_Boot_X, 50, RED, F("SD Can Not Open"));
            #endif

        }

        // Turn SD MUX Enable LOW
        PORTC &= 0b11111110;

        // Set Function Variable
        if (!this->Config.Control.Response) this->Config.Control.Function = false;

    }

#endif
```

Comment: Quick offtopic comment: I cant help you with your problem, but i just want to say that the code snippet you provided is very well written(good variable names, etc) and documented. +1

Comment: what is `this`? what is `this->LoopSize()`?

Comment: Why is it a problem that the file is always 24600 bytes? What size are you expecting to see? I guess you're using an SD card library for the `SD` class - which library?

Comment: I think you forgot to write the instruction which writes to the file. Your code doesn't write to the file.